# Launch grails command from grails application

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to run a grails command like "grails help" from a Grails application but all the tries I have done end up with "Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter".

Basically, I have tried

```
def p1 = "grails help".execute()
p1.waitFor()

println "return code: ${ p1.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${p1.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${p1.in.text}"
```

Also:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
Process process = runtime.exec("grails help")
process.waitFor()

println "return code: ${ process.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${process.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${process.in.text}"
```

And finally:

```
def sout = new StringBuffer()
def serr = new StringBuffer()
final processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder()
processBuilder.directory(new File("/myFolder"))
processBuilder.command(["grails","help"])
println processBuilder.directory()
Process proc = processBuilder.start()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)

def status = proc.waitFor()
println 'sout: ' + sout
println 'serr: ' + serr
```

Of course, the "grails help" command is not the one I want to execute but fixing this one it will fix the one I need to run.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I create a new app with grails 2.3.5 (`grails create-app script-test`), then declare a controller (`grails create-controller test.Run`) and change it so it looks like:

```
package test

class RunController {
    def index() {
        def t = [ 'grails', 'help' ].execute().text
        render "<pre>$t</pre>"
    }
}
```

Then run it with `grails run-app`, and go to `localhost:8080/script-test/run`, I get the grails help screen rendered as text to the web-page.

The problem you are going to have is that this won't work in production as you are probably going to deploy a `war` file, so grails won't be aware of where you are, or what you are doing (if indeed grails is installed on the server)

I think you need to re-think your strategy, whatever it is you are trying to do :-(

Comment: But what about using the env var GRAILS_HOME? I found that processBuilder.command([env['GRAILS_HOME']+"/bin/grails","help"]) will make the trick. Don't you think it is going to work on production? I haven't still tested in prod.

Comment: I use `gvm` to install grails, and so have `grails` on my path (and `GRAILS_HOME` set to `/Users/me/.gvm/grails/current`) so it works without any changes.  It depends how you deploy to production.  We deploy war files to a server with no knowledge of the grails binaries, so for us this wouldn't work

Comment: No worries :-)  Good luck with it all :-)